# laravel clone with integer column

Tags: php, laravel

I want to clone my orders in order to let users re-order but I have `orderstatus_id` column which is integer for getting status of orders.

The issue is if user clone `completed` (any status) order cloned order will be the same status as old one, what I want is to get my `orderstatus` id `1` which is `waiting payment` in my case, so the cloned order status will be `waiting payment` and not `completed`. when I try `$newOrder->orderstatus_id = 1;` I will get this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails

here is my clone code:

```
public function reorder($id)
    {
      $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
      $newOrder = $order->replicate();
      $newOrder->orderstatus_id = 1;
      $newOrder->save();

      return redirect()->back()
          ->with('info',
           'Order Stored');
    }
```

any idea?

## update

`Orders` table schema

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
          $table->text('cart');
          $table->integer('orderstatus_id')->unsigned();
          $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
          $table->string('payment_id');
          $table->timestamps();
      });
      Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
          $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
          $table->foreign('orderstatus_id')->references('id')->on('orderstatuses');
      });
```

`orderstatuses` table schema

```
Schema::create('orderstatuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Does 1 refer to a field of the table bind to orderstatus_id ?

Comment: Can you give the complete fields for `order` table? Since from your exception it's caused by foreign key.

Comment: @JimWright as I said `
      $newOrder->orderstatus_id = 1;`

Comment: @Goms yes it's id of `orderstatuses` table.

Comment: You're not going to get an exception on that line... If anything the next line.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra what do you need exactly to i share?

Comment: @JimWright well this is all i have already shared my function.

Comment: You should post your table schema as well. There is an index that we need to see.

Comment: @JimWright schema of orders table or orderstatus?

Comment: @JimWright Updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in `orderstatus` with id 1?

Comment: @JimWright no it was orders table schema, I added `orderstatuses` table schema as well.

Comment: #Solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237829/get-id-of-where-query-in-laravel#48237847