# Get id of where query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to duplicate my orders and there is `orderstatus_id` column which will get orders status id, while duplicating order(s) I want to change the order status id from whatever it is to specific id.

## need more explain?

my order status is `completed` with id `11`, I want copy it and in copied order status become `waiting payment` which is id `1`. during this process I want to get that id dynamically because i don't know in future id's will stay the same or not.

so I have code like:

```
//re-order
  public function reorder($id)
    {
      $status = Orderstatus::where('title', 'Witing Payment')->select('id')->get();
      $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
      $newOrder = $order->replicate();
      $newOrder->ordernu = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
      $newOrder->orderstatus_id = $status;
      $newOrder->payment_id = '';
      $newOrder->save();

      return redirect()->back()
          ->with('info',
           'Order Stored');
    }
```

when I hit copy link i get this error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

what i need is fix for this line, (I guess)

```
$status = Orderstatus::where('title', 'Witing Payment')->select('id')->get();
```

thanks.

## update

Screenshot of my order table (as you see all my integer columns are nullable)

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because some foreign key is empty. Looks like it's `payment_id`. If you want to allow it to be empty, you need to make it nullable in migration:

```
$table->string('payment_id')->nullable();
```

Also, change this:

```
Orderstatus::where('title', 'Witing Payment')->select('id')->get();
```

To:

```
Orderstatus::where('title', 'Witing Payment')->value('id');
```

Comment: even if I remove that line, and let to be copied from old order still i get same error, I don't think is related to payment_id. + my payment_id is nullable.

Comment: I included screenshot.

Comment: @mafortis please show migration class for the `OrderStatus` and results of `dd($newOrder);` placed right before `$newOrder->save();`

Comment: it's working just fine now :-D all it need was that value('id'), thanks man, appreciate it.